# how to render a scraped tweet from his json?

Tags: json, web-scraping, twitter, tweets, html-rendering

I'm trying to be able to render (html/css) tweets that I **scrape** in the form of [object-models](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet) (JSON) on this endpoint type currently:
https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/tweet?id=1455800444505178112

I only want the essentials (like this JSON) for obvious storage reasons and all the necessary information is here !

I can't really use the [embedded tweets](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/embedded-tweets/overview) which is based on twitter sources (because of course I want to **be able to display canceled tweets**).

Do you have any idea how i could do this ?
Has one of you ever done it ?
Is there another way to do it ?

*I find it a shame that everyone scrapes tweets but no one tries to be able to put them back visually in the light of the general public in the event of cancellation.*

Example of [object-model](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet) :

```
{
    "lang": "en",
    "favorite_count": 360261,
    "self_thread": {
        "id_str": "1455800444505178112"
    },
    "created_at": "2021-11-03T07:34:08.000Z",
    "display_text_range": [...],
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [],
        "urls": [],
        "user_mentions": [],
        "symbols": [],
        "media": [
            {
                "display_url": "...",
                "expanded_url": "...",
                "indices": [...],
                "url": "..."
            }
        ]
    },
    "id_str": "1455800444505178112",
    "text": "Yup, even the moon https:...",
    "user": {
        "id_str": "44196397",
        "name": "Elon Musk",
        "profile_image_url_https": "...",
        "screen_name": "elonmusk",
        "verified": true
    },
    "photos": [
        {
            "backgroundColor": {...},
            "cropCandidates": [...],
            "expandedUrl":...",
            "url": "...",
            "width": 553,
            "height": 441
        }
    ],
    "conversation_count": 40684,
    "news_action_type": "conversation"
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: Your question is a bit broad for this forum.  
If you want to "rebuild" twitter's timeline and you already have the data then you're only missing the template. Look into `jinja2` or other html templating languages and create a html template that can expand your json into a proper html body.